# Page won't redirect to the right page

Tags: php, redirect, host

I have uploaded a login/register site on Godaddy for some reason the pages won't redirect properly and it works fine testing on local host, any help will be appreciated!

This is the code for my register.php page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Register page</title>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes.css">
<style type="text/css">
p.error { color:red; font-size:105%; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<?php include("register-header.php"); ?>
<?php include("nav.php"); ?>
<?php include("info-col.php"); ?>
    <div id="content"><!-- Start of the register page content -->
<p><?php
require ('mysqli_connect.php'); // Connect to the database.
// If the form has been submitted, insert a record in the users table
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $errors = array(); // Initialize an error array
    // Check for a first name:
    if (empty($_POST['fname'])) {
        $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your first name.';
    } else {
        //$fn = trim($_POST['fname']);
            $fn = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, trim($_POST['fname']));
    }
    // Check for a last name:
    if (empty($_POST['lname'])) {
        $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your last name.';
    } else {
        //$ln = trim($_POST['lname']);
        //$ln = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $ln);
        $ln = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, trim($_POST['lname']));
    }
    // Check for an email address
    if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your email address.';
    } else {
        $e = trim($_POST['email']);
    }
    // Check for a password then match it against the confirmed password:
    if (!empty($_POST['psword1'])) {
        if ($_POST['psword1'] != $_POST['psword2']) {
            $errors[] = 'Your two password did not match.';
        } else {
            $p = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, trim($_POST['psword1']));
        }
    } else {
        $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your password.';
    }
    if (empty($errors)) { // If everything's OK
    // Register the user in the database...
        // Make the query:
        $q = "INSERT INTO users (user_id, fname, lname, email, psword, registration_date) VALUES (' ', '$fn', '$ln', '$e', SHA1('$p'), NOW() )";        
        $result = @mysqli_query ($dbcon, $q); // Run the query.
        if ($result) { // If it ran OK
        header ("location: register-thanks.php"); 
        exit();
        // Echo a message:
        //echo '<h2>Thank you!</h2>
        //<p>You are now registered.</p><p><br></p>';   
        } else { // If it did not run OK
        // Error message:
            echo '<h2>System Error</h2>
            <p class="error">You could not be registered due to a system error. We apologize for any inconvenience.</p>'; 
            // Debugging message:
            echo '<p>' . mysqli_error($dbcon) . '<br><br>Query: ' . $q . '</p>';
        } // End of if ($result)
        mysqli_close($dbcon); // Close the database connection.
        // Include the footer and stop the script
        include ('footer.php'); 
        //header ("location: register-thanks.php"); 
        //exit();
    } else { // Report the errors
        echo '<h2>Error!</h2>
        <p class="error">The following error(s) occurred:<br>';
        foreach ($errors as $msg) { // Echo each error
            echo " - $msg<br>\n";
        }
        echo '</p><h3>Please try again.</h3><p><br></p>';
        }// End of if (empty($errors))
} // End of the main Submit conditional
?>
<h2>Register</h2>
<form action="register-page.php" method="post">
    <p><label class="label" for="fname">First Name:</label><input id="fname" type="text" name="fname" size="30" maxlength="30" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['fname'])) echo $_POST['fname']; ?>"></p>
    <p><label class="label" for="lname">Last Name:</label><input id="lname" type="text" name="lname" size="30" maxlength="40" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['lname'])) echo $_POST['lname']; ?>"></p>
    <p><label class="label" for="email">Email Address:</label><input id="email" type="text" name="email" size="30" maxlength="60" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['email'])) echo $_POST['email']; ?>" > </p>
    <p><label class="label" for="psword1">Password:</label><input id="psword1" type="password" name="psword1" size="12" maxlength="12" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['psword1'])) echo $_POST['psword1']; ?>" >&nbsp;Between 8 and 12 characters.</p>
    <p><label class="label" for="psword2">Confirm Password:</label><input id="psword2" type="password" name="psword2" size="12" maxlength="12" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['psword2'])) echo $_POST['psword2']; ?>" ></p>
    <p><input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Register"></p>
</form>
<?php include ('footer.php'); ?></p>
    <!-- End of the register page content -->
</div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Turn on error reporting and it might give you a hint. Also, when you're stuck on something, try to create a minimal example that reproduces the problem. In this case, had you tried to do just a redirect, you'd see that it works. So, the problem is something else... start isolating and testing. What you've done here is dumped a load of code on us and say, "Why doesn't it do what I want?" -- you'll never learn like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have output before your `header()` call. There must be absolute no output before it. If you turn on error reporting you'll probably see a warning about "Headers already sent".

Move your login code at the absolute beginning of the page, store any messages for later display.